# Support for foreign key constraint in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

In Ruby on Rails, how to add foreign key constraint in migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't any built-in support for that, but there are [several plugins](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/search?q=foreign+keys) that help you with that. You can also add them manually to your migration files, just use the execute method for that, e.g. (sample from Rails API):

```
  class MakeJoinUnique < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      execute "ALTER TABLE `pages_linked_pages` ADD UNIQUE `page_id_linked_page_id` (`page_id`,`linked_page_id`)"
    end

    def self.down
      execute "ALTER TABLE `pages_linked_pages` DROP INDEX `page_id_linked_page_id`"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Old post, but in case anyone sees this: a unique index is not equivalent to a foreign key constraint, so I believe this code doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a gem-based solution that includes support for adding and removing foreign key constraints, doesn't fail with sqlite, and works correctly with schema.rb files:

http://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner

Comment: FYI, `foreigner` doesn't generate foreign keys in `schema.rb` when using SQLite, because SQLite doesn't support foreign keys.

Answer (score 4):

This is an update to the matthuhiggins-foreigner gem: http://github.com/sparkfly/foreigner

Features:

- rspec coverage, tested against PostgreSQL 8.3.9 and MySQL 5.0.90
- Migration support
- schema.rb support

Future versions will include CHECK constraints for PostgreSQL, which is needed to implement multi-table inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. the foreigner gem does not work well with the change method especially if the table has not been created before. This works great

Comment: Your welcomed. Let me know (through github) if you find any bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough with adding the following, for example with `Products` and `User` models?

`add_index :products, :user_id`

Comment: Adding an index will certainly help with query performance, but it will not make a database enforce foreign key constraints.